# Jackson mapping to POJO cannot deserialize instance instance

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, pojo

I am receiving data in a Jackson format and want to read it into a POJO I have defined. I am either badly defining the POJO or missing some key step. The data format being received is in the format below:

```
{
    streetSegment: [
    {
        distance: "0.04",
        highway: "residential",
        name: "Swift",
        line: "-1.6720224 52.6251985,-1.6721061 52.6250432,-1.6721799,             52.6248908,-1.6721996 52.6247594",
        wayId: "76473524"
    },
    {
        distance: "0.05",
        highway: "residential",
        name: "Swift",
        line: "-1.6721799 52.6248908,-1.6723374 52.6248669,-1.6732035 52.6249774,-1.6734643 52.6249894",
        wayId: "76473523"
    }
    ]
}
```

I have defined the POJO as:

```
public class StreetSegment {

public static class Street {
    private String distance;
    private String highway;
    private String name;
    private String line;
    private String wayId;
    public Street() {
        super();
    }
    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public String getHighway() {
        return highway;
    }
    public void setHighway(String highway) {
        this.highway = highway;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
    public String getWayId() {
        return wayId;
    }
    public void setWayId(String wayId) {
        this.wayId = wayId;
    }
}
```

}

When I read the object mapper with the following line:

```
List<StreetSegment> list = mObjectMapper.readValue( in, new TypeReference<List<StreetSegment>>(){} );
```

I get an exception as shown:

```
10-18 12:49:57.596: W/System.err(31776): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
10-18 12:49:57.596: W/System.err(31776):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@42ea8038; line: 1, column: 1]
10-18 12:49:57.606: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
10-18 12:49:57.616: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:569)
10-18 12:49:57.616: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
10-18 12:49:57.626: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
10-18 12:49:57.626: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:207)
10-18 12:49:57.636: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
10-18 12:49:57.636: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
10-18 12:49:57.646: W/System.err(31776):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2041)
10-18 12:49:57.646: W/System.err(31776):    at co.uk.dominion.test.MainActivity$19._getStreetSegmentFromURL(MainActivity.java:3428)
10-18 12:49:57.646: W/System.err(31776):    at co.uk.dominion.test.MainActivity$19.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:3460)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at co.uk.dominion.test.MainActivity$19.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-18 12:49:57.656: W/System.err(31776):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I also tried defining as a JsonNode first to see if I could spot the issue but to no avail:

```
JsonNode node = mObjectReader.readValue(in);
List<StreetSegment> list = mObjectMapper.readValue(node.toString(), new TypeReference<List<StreetSegment>>(){});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `Street` by this way:

**Street**

```
public class Street {
    private List<StreetSegment> streetSegment;

    public Street() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public List<StreetSegment> getStreetSegment() {
        return streetSegment;
    }

    public void setStreetSegment(List<StreetSegment> streetSegment) {
        this.streetSegment = streetSegment;
    }
}
```

**StreetSegment**

```
public class StreetSegment {
    private String distance;
    private String highway;
    private String name;
    private String line;
    private String wayId;

    public StreetSegment() {

    }
    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public String getHighway() {
        return highway;
    }
    public void setHighway(String highway) {
        this.highway = highway;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
    public String getWayId() {
        return wayId;
    }
    public void setWayId(String wayId) {
        this.wayId = wayId;
    }
}
```

To check it, here is `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String str = "{" + 
                "    \"streetSegment\": [" + 
                "        {" + 
                "            \"distance\": \"0.04\"," + 
                "            \"highway\": \"residential\"," + 
                "            \"name\": \"Swift\"," + 
                "            \"line\": \"-1.6720224 52.6251985,-1.6721061 52.6250432,-1.6721799,             52.6248908,-1.6721996 52.6247594\"," + 
                "            \"wayId\": \"76473524\"" + 
                "        }," + 
                "        {" + 
                "            \"distance\": \"0.05\"," + 
                "            \"highway\": \"residential\"," + 
                "            \"name\": \"Swift\"," + 
                "            \"line\": \"-1.6721799 52.6248908,-1.6723374 52.6248669,-1.6732035 52.6249774,-1.6734643 52.6249894\"," + 
                "            \"wayId\": \"76473523\"" + 
                "        }" + 
                "    ]" + 
                "}";
    // to simulate stream reader    
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes())); 

     BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(in); 

    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

    String inputStr;
    while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
        buff.append(inputStr);


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Street mj = mapper.readValue(buff.toString(), Street.class);

        if(mj == null){
            System.err.println("null");
        }                
    }
```

Checking...

```
System.out.println(mj.getStreetSegment().get(0).getHighway());//dummy print
```

Output: `residential`

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. What odd is that your code works and yet when it is used with JsonNode and node.toString() it doesn't. I have compared the strings side by side and they seem the same.

Comment: In my case `StreetSegment` is not child of Street. I dont use `super()`

Comment: I took that out of mine to match your definition of StreetSegment. Just noticed I am now seeing this in the stack trace, I don't know what ref is... UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ref" (class co.uk.dominion.test.StreetSegment), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "line", "distance", "wayId", "name", "highway"])

Comment: see my edit, i converted String to bytes and use `InputStreamReader `

Comment: Ahhhh! I just realized that sometimes there is also a Ref field in the returned data - what a silly oversight! Thanks you very much for your help, the POJO is now correct!

Comment: @NissrineNakiri generally if any answer helps you, you welcome to upvote. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your models in two seperate classes, viz `StreetSegment` and `Street`.

```
public class StreetSegment {
    list<Street> street_list;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Street {
     private String distance;
     private String highway;
     private String name;
     private String line;
     private String wayId;

      //getters and setters
 }
```

//skip the rest if your problem is solved

I'm guessing you're using `@RequestBody` for getting JSON body of request.
I would use it this way:

```
public your_return_type your_method(@RequestBody String rb) {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    StreetSegment ss = om.readValue(rb, StreetSegment.class);

    //and the rest
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Sorry not sure what you mean by @RequestBody - I am reading the JSON using an InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()) and then processing the InputStreamReader in the object mapper. I tried the changes you and Maxim proposed but I get the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, all sorted whats to Maxims and your help!